# add objects to Binary Search tree using custom comparator?

Tags: java, collections, binary-search-tree, comparable, treeset

I need to add objects to the Binary search tree and want to write my own compareTo method. How should i go about this. Actually i am trying to implement a custom TreeSet. I am confused where to implement a comparator or comparable and define it. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object must be implements interface Comparable

```
class MyClass implements Comparable { 
  int compareTo(){...}
}
final Set set = new TreeSet();
set.add(new MyClass());
....
set.add(new MyClass());
```

or make our own comparator:

```
class MyClass {}

class MyComparator implements Comparator {
    int compareTo(Object o1, Object o2){
      ...
    }
}
final Set set = new TreeSet(new MyComparator());
set.add(new MyClass());
....
set.add(new MyClass());
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to make sure the objects you add to the `TreeSet` implement `Comparable`. This means making sure the stored objects implement a `compareTo` method as defined in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

You probably don't need a `Comparator`.

By the way, we recently created a [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pq0ArQhhWzU) on exactly this topic. Hopefully it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

For a `TreeSet`, you need to give your own implementation of the `Comparator` interface.

Something like this, maybe?

```
// Using an anonymous interface
Set<Foobar> example = new TreeSet<Foobar>(new Comparator<Foobar>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Foobar f1, Foobar f2) {
    // How will you compare f1 and f2??
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // How will you determine if objects are equal?
    return false;
  }
}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below code

```
package com.example.treeset;

    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.TreeSet;

    public class MyCompUser {

        public static void main(String a[]){
            //By using name comparator (String comparison)
            TreeSet<Empl> nameComp = new TreeSet<Empl>(new MyNameComp());
            nameComp.add(new Empl("Ram",3000));
            nameComp.add(new Empl("John",6000));
            nameComp.add(new Empl("Crish",2000));
            nameComp.add(new Empl("Tom",2400));
            for(Empl e:nameComp){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            System.out.println("===========================");
            //By using salary comparator (int comparison)
            TreeSet<Empl> salComp = new TreeSet<Empl>(new MySalaryComp());
            salComp.add(new Empl("Ram",3000));
            salComp.add(new Empl("John",6000));
            salComp.add(new Empl("Crish",2000));
            salComp.add(new Empl("Tom",2400));
            for(Empl e:salComp){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    class MyNameComp implements Comparator<Empl>{

        @Override
        public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) {
            return e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName());
        }
    }   

    class MySalaryComp implements Comparator<Empl>{

        @Override
        public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) {
            if(e1.getSalary() > e2.getSalary()){
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    class Empl{

        private String name;
        private int salary;

        public Empl(String n, int s){
            this.name = n;
            this.salary = s;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public int getSalary() {
            return salary;
        }
        public void setSalary(int salary) {
            this.salary = salary;
        }
        public String toString(){
            return "Name: "+this.name+"-- Salary: "+this.salary;
        }
    }
```